# Angular form.controls['InputName'].value Updating Issue

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue updating the form value with my following example:

#### component.html

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
    <select name="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="dropdown" (ngModelChange)="onDropdownChange($event)">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

#### component.ts

```
export class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild('testForm') public form: NgForm;

    public dropdown: string;

    public onDropdownChange() {
        console.log("this.dropdown: " + this.dropdown);
        console.log("this.form.controls[dropdown].value: " + this.form.controls['dropdown'].value);
    }
}
```

When the page loads, the dropdown is blank. If I select "1", the following is logged:

`this.dropdown: 1`

`this.form.controls[dropdown].value: undefined`

If I then select "2", the following is logged:

`this.dropdown: 2`

`this.form.controls[dropdown].value: 1`

My question is why is this happening and how can I make it so that this.form.controls['dropdown'].value has the most up to date value and isn't "one behind"?

Comment: Can't say I have much experience using ngModelChange. But my best guess is it is firing after the ngModel set event. Try changing (ngModelChange) to the controls native (change) event. Here is a sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7d8q5b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `(ngModelChange)` to `(change)` as below:

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
    <select name="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="dropdown" (change)="onDropdownChange($event)">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to try a simple getter/setter.

**Template**

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
    <select name="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="dropdown">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Notice it has no modelChange or change event

**Component**

```
export class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild('testForm') public form: NgForm;

    private _dropdown;
    get dropdown(): string {
       return this._dropdown;
    }
    set dropdown(value: string) {
        this._dropdown = value;
        console.log("this.dropdown: " + this.dropdown);
        console.log("this.form.controls[dropdown].value: " + this.form.controls['dropdown'].value);
    }
}
```

The setter will be called each time the drop down value changes.

Comment: Thanks, Deborah. Getters/Setters would work too, however, I just decided to use `(change)` instead of `(ngModelChange)`.